# Tomcat Undeploy old versions when a new version is deployed

Tags: tomcat, deployment, application-server

So I was kind of thrown in to looking over these new tomcat servers we have set up.  Our test server works as intended, when a new version is deployed, it sets it's "running" attribute to "true" and deleted the old deployment.

Unfortunately, both of our production servers don't act the same way. The versions are all correct (they are YYYYMMDDHHMMSS), but the "running" attribute is "false" and the old deployments don't get deleted - which will eventually cause more issues.

Is this something that can be changed in the tomcat manager UI?  I haven't been able to see a difference between our test and prod servers yet.

EDIT: Should mention that I am using Maven and TeamCity to build/ssh over to tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am using Maven to build this, and it seems a parameter was missing in my production config, but Maven was still allowing a succesful build.

Not sure on this part, but I think tomcat knew something wasn't right and automatically defaulted to the most recent working deployment.  Once I added the parameter and deployed, tomcat correctly undeployed the old deployment and set my new one to Running.